# how do I add 'modal-open' class to the body after closing a modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I'm aware that overlapping modals isn't a supported feature within bootstrap 3.3.7 however it's a feature that I would like to use.

The issue I've run into is when I call `$('#modal').modal('hide');` on the second modal that is open. It removes the class `"modal-open"` from the body. This means that even though the first modal is still open the focus is on the page below that modal. I've tried manually re adding the class using `$(document.body).addClass('modal-open')` but no luck as it is added and then removed.

Comment: This is in no way a fix but in the mean time until I figure this out I have added `modal-open` to a div that surrounds the rest of the app and is one layer down from the body. This has solved the issue for me however one of the side effects is that when you close the second modal and refocus on the first two scrollbars are now visible. One for the modal you are on and one for the background. I don't intend on keeping this functionality but this works for now.

Comment: I should also mention in reference to my previous comment that when I add `modal-open` to the div it is done `onclick` on the button that closes the second modal and not hard coded.